# Count the number of non empty columns in R

Tags: r

I want to add a column in a dataframe that adds up the number of non-empty values for each row.
The total column shows the end result that is required:

```
col1<-c("Yes","No",  "Yes",  NA,  NA)
col2<-c("Yes",NA,    NA,    "No","Yes")
col3<-c("Yes",   "Yes", "No",   NA   ,NA)
Total<-c(3,2,2,1,1)
data<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3,Total, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use vectorized `rowSums` on a logical matrix

```
data$Total <- rowSums(!is.na(data[1:3]))
data$Total
[1] 3 2 2 1 1
```